# Error while generating dataset- ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0

Tags: dataset, text-to-speech, audio-processing

I am attempting to create an audio dataset for text-to-speech synthesis by training the Tacotron 2 model. Initially, I'm using around 30 samples of my own voice. However, I encountered an error that states:

"ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0."

You can access the Colab notebook I'm using at the following link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b_wJtEWN69TTMEc3l-xMj6-p32NUx_AW#scrollTo=6JlOH2UTmv2E

I have already double-checked the file path and attempted to upload the files manually. The dataset I am using is not empty. I also tried running the code both with and without preprocessing, but I am still unable to identify the cause of the error.